# update table using select from one table records that doesnt' exist in another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, subquery

I know basic SQL, but not complex.

I have two tables [Table 1 & Table 2] which has username and memberid common in both. There are records in Table 1 where it doesn't exist in Table 2.

For ex. if i needed to pull all the records from Table 1 which doesn't have a matching record in Table 2, using the username as filter, I will write something like this:

```
select * from Table1 a
  where  not exists (select * from Table2 b 
                 where b.MemberID = a.MemberID) and UserName like 'b%'
```

That was easy. But, how do I update all these results with a different username ?.

I'm trying to find all the records in Table1 for the same username  which doesn't have a matching record in Table 2, and then update those records with my username ('r%').

I know some will ask, what have you tried...I have tried to use the 2 queries as single, but getting lots of error...for ex:

```
update Table1
   set UserName = (select * from Table1 a
   where  not exists (select * from Table2 b 
     where b.MemberID = a.MemberID) and UserName = 'r@gmail.com')
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What error are you getting? Maybe change Not Exists to Not In?

Comment: not in throwing error as incorrect syntax.  The error with 'not exist' is "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE TAB1
SET    USERNAME = (SELECT TOP 1 USERNAME
                   FROM   TABLE1 A
                   WHERE  USERNAME LIKE 'r%')
FROM   TABLE1 TAB1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   TABLE2 B
                   WHERE  B.MEMBERID = TAB1.MEMBERID)
       AND TAB1.UserName LIKE 'b%'
```

Comment: Hi @Pradeep, i think, this would update all the other rows with r%, but i want specify that the rows needed to update with a different username where username is b%

Answer (score 1):

This should update the rows in Table1 that match your first query.

```
update Table1
set UserName = 'r@gmail.com'
from (select * from Table1 a
where  not exists (select * from Table2 b 
             where b.MemberID = a.MemberID) and UserName like 'b%')
```

Comment: Thanks @JayL, but this gives "Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near ''."  I tried to remove the last ' and ran it and it gives "Incorrect syntax near ')'."

Answer (score 1):

With SQL 2008 and later you can use the MERGE command for making complex changes to one table based on the contents of another table.

```
MERGE INTO Table2 AS Target
USING Table1 AS Source ON Source.MemberID = Target.MemberID AND Source.UserName = Target.UserName
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE Target SET [ExtraField] = Source.[SourceField]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT INTO Target(MemberID, UserName,ExtraField) VALUES (Source.MemberID, Source.UserName, Source.SourceField)
```

Comment: Thanks LeeG, i haven't tried this out, since @Pradeep's solution worked.  But i will def. try this out and will let you know of the outcome, sooner.